# consulta retardada en una condicion phpmyadmin

Tags: php

Estoy realizando dos tipos de consultas. Cuando coloco de referencia un campo, la consulta se realiza en 4 segundos pero cuando no coloco referencia tiende a tardar 30 segundos.

Esta es la que tarda 30 segundos :

```
if(cliente == "" && termPago=="0" && moneda=="0" && estado=="0")
 { query = "SELECT f.idFactura, e.nombreEmpleado, f.fecha,
c.nombreCliente, c.nomenclaturaCliente, t.nombreTipo AS 'estado',
 t1.nombreTipo AS 'terminoPago', t2.nombreTipo AS 'tipoFactura',
 f.comentario, f.total, t3.nombreTipo AS 'moneda' FROM
 encabezadofactura f INNER JOIN cliente c ON f.clienteID = c.idCliente
 INNER JOIN tipos t on f.estadoFactura = t.idTipos INNER JOIN tipos t1 
 on f.terminosPago = t1.idTipos INNER JOIN tipos t2 on f.tipoFactura =
 t2.idTipos INNER JOIN tipos t3 on f.moneda = t3.idTipos INNER JOIN
 empleado e ON  f.empleadoID = e.idEmpleado WHERE f.fecha BETWEEN
 '"+desde+"' AND '"+hasta+"'  ORDER BY f.idFactura ASC";     }
```

Esta la realiza en 3 segundos:

```
>      else if(estado != "0" && termPago == "0" && moneda == "0" && client == "") 
>     {  query = "SELECT f.idFactura, e.nombreEmpleado, f.fecha, 
>     c.nombreCliente, c.nomenclaturaCliente, t.nombreTipo AS 'estado',
>      t1.nombreTipo AS 'terminoPago', t2.nombreTipo AS 'tipoFactura', f.comentario, f.total, t3.nombreTipo AS 'moneda' FROM
> encabezadofactura f INNER JOIN cliente c ON f.clienteID = c.idCliente
> INNER JOIN tipos t on f.estadoFactura = t.idTipos INNER JOIN tipos t1
> on f.terminosPago = t1.idTipos INNER JOIN tipos t2 on f.tipoFactura =
> t2.idTipos INNER JOIN tipos t3 on f.moneda = t3.idTipos INNER JOIN
> empleado e ON f.empleadoID = e.idEmpleado WHERE f.fecha BETWEEN
> '"+desde+"' AND '"+hasta+"' AND f.estadoFactura="+estado+" ORDER BY
> f.idFactura ASC";
>      }
```

Las relaciones las tengo de manera correcta, el problema se genera cuando no coloco ninguna referencia o cuando solo coloco el nombre de cliente.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Haría falta más información para saber las causas (p.e. la estructura de las tablas y su relación, el motor de base de datos que estás usando, etc.), pero la razón más probable es que al añadir f.estadoFactura a la consulta, estás haciéndola más restrictiva y más eficiente porque se tienen que revisar menos campos (puedes hacer un `explain` en tu base de datos para verlo).

Comment: aparentemente tienes un índice en `estadoFactura` que permite descartar muchas filas a priori, lo cual acelera la consulta.

Comment: El problema es que una consulta tarda mas que la otra, cuando deberia tardar menos cuando no se coloca una referencia de busqueda sino que simplemente trae todos los datos.